# Some doubts about package with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I'm new working with Vagrant. I have some doubts about the package command, because I did some changes in my basebox **precise32.box** and i want to reuse this box but I want to know what is meaning of [vm-name] parameter because it not appears on --help report.

And what kind of files can be packaged with the box?

```js
roberto@rcisla-pc:~$ vagrant package --help
Usage: vagrant package [vm-name] [--base name] [--output name.box]
                       [--include one,two,three] [--vagrantfile file]

        --base NAME                  Name of a VM in virtualbox to package as a base box
        --output NAME                Name of the file to output
        --include x,y,z              Additional files to package with the box.
        --vagrantfile file           Vagrantfile to package with the box.
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've packaged 50+ vagrant boxes but never used the `[vn-name]` argument.

In fact, the official documentation does not mention it at all => see [vagrant package](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html)

I've been using the following all the time.

`vagrant package --base name --output /path/to/name.box`

You can get it by using the following command:

```sh
$ VBoxManage list vms
"Windows XP" {fa768a76-5710-4b07-a4df-cc388370f038}
"archlinux" {c79dcee9-a523-4300-b026-cbc93ad37062}
"XenServer" {723b2acb-57cf-43ae-8202-f3a939924d20}
"Xen" {4491c002-51dc-40b8-941f-b6649b3b7d74}
```

You can use the Name or UUID of the VM.